# Does the FCC e-mail when a vanity call sign is approved?

Tags: united-states, legal, callsign

I submitted an application for a vanity call sign [a little over 18 days ago](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/16426/17659), and it's marked "pending". I presume that it will be processed soon, but the FCC's ULS search page is being slow and glitchy. Will the FCC e-mail me when the application is approved or rejected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120047/discussion-between-mike-waters-and-chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 2021, the FCC **will** send an e-mail to your address on file when your application is approved with a link to your updated license PDF (but no details in the e-mail body itself). It will be sent later on the day your batch is processed; mine was sent at 17:55 ET.